# If G is finite then $\Phi(G)$ is nilpotent.

Tags: group-theory

Okay I am trying to solve the problem

> If G is finite then $\Phi(G)$ is nil-potent.

I think I should prove that if $\{M_i\}$ is the collection of maximal subgroups of $\Phi(G)$ then $N_{\Phi(G)}(M_i)=\Phi(G)$ for all i. But I find it hard to come to prove this statement by contradiction, being that I don't know how the existence of an $M_i$ such that $N_{\Phi(G)}(M_i)=M_i)$ gives a contradiction.

Any Ideas?

$\Phi(G)=\bigcap H_j$ where $\{H_j\}$ is a collection of all maximal subgroups of G.

$\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup. Also if a finite group $G'$ is nilpotent then I have already proved that every maximal subgroup must be normal.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what $\Phi$ means, or at least use some words I could look up?

Comment: It is called the frattini subgroup.

Comment: Please edit the question to add that detail. Important information should not be relegated to comments. (Giving the definition but not the name the whole universe knows this subgroup by is only half of it!)

Comment: (Fratttini is a person, so we capitalize his name :-) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard textbook result. It is enough to prove that any Sylow subgroup $P$ of $\Phi(G)$ is normal in $\Phi(G)$ (that is an equivalent condition to nilpotency for finite groups). In fact more is true: $P$ is normal in $G$.

By the Frattini Argument, we have $G = \Phi(G)N_G(P)$. But now if $N_G(P) \ne G$, then $N_G(P) \le M$ for some maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$. But $\Phi(G) \le M$, so we get $G=\Phi(G) N_G(P) \le M$, contradiction.